# Measuring momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, wavefunction, observables, wavefunction-collapse

I'm new here, possibly my apologies for misplacing.

After a measurement in quantum mechanics, the wavefunction collapses to an eigenstate corresponding to the outcome of the measurement. Thus if we want to apply this to the momentum observable, the outcome of the impulse can be random, but after the measurement, we know the wavefunction, namely an eigenstate of the impulse operator. But such an eigenstate corresponds to a state where the particle can be everywhere. At first look, this seems logical because we know the impulse exactly. But then I'm confused; how we can measure momentum without disturbing the position too much? It looks that we need an inaccurate observable.

Comment: Hi uncertain. In fact after a real measurement it does not seem that you get an exact momentum eigenstate, only an approximate one. But it is true, you cannot measure momentum without disturbing the position. And it seems to be the case that more accurate measurements of momentum disturb the position more.